# Is it possible to execute each task inside a playbbok in a different host?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with two tasks. I want execute the first on `my_machine1` and the second in `my_machine2`. Is it possible? I want it to be synchronous: since first task has not finished I don't want the second starts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [delegation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation)

You can use `delegate_to` keyword on a task to make it run on an other host like this:

```
- name: take out of load balancer pool
  command: /usr/bin/take_out_of_pool {{ inventory_hostname }}
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

As pointed out in the documentation

> Using this with the ‘serial’ keyword to control the number of hosts executing at one time is also a good idea